# Connecting to an Oracle database in Ecliipse works, fails with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven

I have some Java which connects to an oracle database, within Eclipse, I configured the buildpath to point to the ojdbc6.jar file and when I run inside Eclipse there are no issues.

However when I try and tun in maven (using mvn clean test) I get a class not found error.  In Eclipse I added the ojdbc6 jar file to the order and export but still no joy (confirmed that there were changes in the .classpath file)

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised the error - and was simple - forgot to include the jar in the POM.xml